# Shape looks cut off / cropped

Tags: inkscape

I have strange issues modifying a shape in Inkscape. I am designing a number `3`, but see the screenshots.

When selected, the selection rectangle only covers a part of the shape:

[image: Selected]

When editing, the edit nodes are in the correct place:

[image: Edit mode]

When I hover over the shape, the outline seems correct:

[image: Outline]

I have tried:

- saving the file and reopening - unfortunately it does not help.
- menu Object / Mask / Release
- menu Object / Clip / Release

What could I have done wrong and how to undo that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you make a clipping mask or the corresponding action in Inkscape. Try to ungroup (multiple times, if necessary) to show your entire shape again.

Comment: I'll try to reproduce the behavior to identify how I ended up in that situation

Comment: Ok, whatever that is, it was part of an imported shape. I could reproduce it on that imported shape. I needed to ungroup it twice until the effect was gone.

Comment: I incorporated the need to ungroup multiple times into the answer @ThomasWeller