# Shape looks cut off / cropped - different problem?

Tags: inkscape, crop, clipping-mask

https://sky-walker.net/temp/test/liquid.svg

[image]

The problem is similar to this:

[Shape looks cut off / cropped](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/113042/shape-looks-cut-off-cropped)

I have tried:

- saving the file and reopening - unfortunately it does not help.
- menu Object / Mask / Release
- menu Object / Clip / Release
- ungroup (multiple times, if necessary) to show your entire shape again.

Comment: Added Inkscape tag based upon XML data in SVG file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a drop shadow SVG filter, but the shapes are being cropped by the dimensions of Flood effect of the filter.

To fix it, open the SVG in Inkscape (since it was created in Inkscape).

1. Select one of the objects, and click *Filters > Filter Editor*
2. In the filter editor select the "Flood" effect, and select the Filter General Settings tab.
3. Manually adjust the co-ordinates and dimensions so that the Flood effect is bigger than the extent of the shape and its shadow.

Repeat for the other objects.

[image]

Comment: It's very tedious but it works!

Comment: Going to be much easier in Inkscape 1.0 : https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Release_notes/1.0#Filters

Comment: @Moini - that looks great!