# Inkscape - adding filter to thick vertical or horizontal line clips them

Tags: inkscape

Inkscape document:

https://sky-walker.net/temp/test/different-single-lines.svg

I am using single thick lines. If they are diagonal they basically work with filters. If they become more horizontal or vertical, they become clipped if you apply a filter. For those, the "Flood" parameters can be adjusted so that the filter is displayed properly. See:

[Shape looks cut off / cropped - different problem?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/131252/shape-looks-cut-off-cropped-different-problem)

But if the line is completely vertical or horizontal, when a filter is applied the view is cut off completely, even when I try to adjust the "Flood" parameters.

I have tried different filters but intially want drop shadow (inner or outer) to work.

Without filters:

[image: Without filters]

Inner drop shadow:

[image: Drop shadow - inner]

Outer drop shadow:

[image: Drop shadow - outer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjusting the flood dimensions and co-ordinates works for me. Make sure you have the object selected first before trying to edit the flood.

However, when applying an inner drop shadow you could skip these flood adjustment steps entirely by converting the stroke to outlines first.

Select the object and do *Path > Stroke to Path*. Now apply the filter.

[image]

Note: if you are using an outer drop shadow you may still need to adjust the flood dimensions and co-ordinates if the blur is bigger than the flood.

Another possibility to get around this is to create a larger rectangle around the object with no fill and no stroke, and then group this with the object. Then apply the drop shadow.

Comment: Hi I edited your answer to show the most helpful part. I included the rest too even though I didn't find that useful.

Comment: BTW I can use a single large rectangle around all 4 lines, group them, then apply filters on all of them.

Comment: @LukeWenke Sure, that'll work.

Comment: I have removed the tick because I didn't find most of the answer helpful. Please add another answer that says something like "create a larger rectangle around the object with no fill and no stroke, and then group this with the object. Then apply the drop shadow."

Comment: The additional grouping is a workaround, while adjusting the filtered area is a fix. I think Billy's answer hits the mark, even though you might find another solution more useful to yourself.

Comment: @LukeWenke -that's already part of my answer and is included in the last paragraph. As Moini has said, the rectangle group solution is a merely a workaround. I feel the best way to do it is to adjust the flood dimensions manually.

Comment: For my project I'm using a lot of single or double lines. I'm not using "Stroke to Path", etc. The answer you gave at the end is the solution I'm using now. I guess your main solution would help other people so I'll just accept the whole answer.

Comment: Well I ended up using "Stroke to Path" - for exporting to Blender